# Positioning circle directly behind objects

Tags: html, css

How would I get the circular arrow behind the 7 items I have created. Similar to what shows in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrY5.jpg I cant get it to work for some reason. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.container .row {text-align:center; position:relative;}
.center {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.left {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.right {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left:-35px;
}

.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#006850;
  width:85px;
  height:85px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fefefe;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom:-15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:130px;
  height:65px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#d6d6d6;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color:#d0d3d8;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -22px;
  margin: auto;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 106px;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you have to change the `position` of `.arrow` and change it's `z-index` to `-1` to get that back. No need to `rotate` that `circle` instead change positioning of pseudo selector `:before` and `:after`.

```css
.container .row {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 130px;
  height: 65px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: -1;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -10px;
  left: 55px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers @ColeGwozdecki :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `.container` this CSS style:

```
.container {
  margin-top: -17px;
  height: 313px;
  width: 371px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Surround everything inside `.container` with another div with the id `stuff` except the `.arrow` div.

Give `.stuff` the following styles:

```
.stuff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Add the following CSS line to `.arrow`

```
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Move the `.arrow` div *before* the `.stuff` div

And that should work.

Here is the result I got:

[image]

```css
.container {
  height: 313px;
  width: 371px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -17px;
}
.container .row {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 130px;
  height: 65px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -22px;
  margin: auto;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 106px;
  right: -25px;
}
.stuff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="stuff">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="invisible"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
      <div class="invisible"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="invisible"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="invisible"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To resize it and rotate it, you need to add this to the `.arrow` CSS:

```
  transform: rotate(-112deg) scale(1.2);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 313px;
  width: 371px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -17px;
}
.container .row {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #006850;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1f497d;
  width: 130px;
  height: 65px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  color: #d0d3d8;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: rotate(-112deg) scale(1.2);
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -22px;
  margin: auto;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 106px;
  right: -25px;
}
.stuff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="stuff">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="invisible"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
      <div class="invisible"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="invisible"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="invisible"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It needs to go behind it, yours is just showing up right beside it.

Comment: [This](https://s15.postimg.org/bwbwzhatn/Screen_Shot_2017-07-05_at_15.45.53.png) is what I see. To me that looks behind.

Comment: Yes exactly like that, but for some reason mine doesn't look like that. What browser are you on?

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki I am using FireFox 54.0.1 on OSX Sierra

Comment: Ahh maybe that's why, Im using IE. Never the less thanks for the response!

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki What version of IE?

Comment: Yes works awesome now. Could you rotate it and size it like how it is in the photo? I tried doing it but cant make it work.

Comment: Never mind theres still an issue with the browser I believe.

Comment: I am using IE 11 btw

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you have to absolutely positioned your arrow and use z-index to make it above container and below your rows.
Here is the updated snippet:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container .row {
  text-align:center; 
  position:relative;
}
.row{z-index:2;}
.center {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.left {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.right {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left:-35px;
}

.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#006850;
  width:85px;
  height:85px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fefefe;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom:-15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:130px;
  height:65px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#d6d6d6;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-110deg);
  color:#d0d3d8;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 17px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -22px;
  margin: auto;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d0d3d8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 130px;
  right: -26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you rotate it and size it like how It is in the photo? Im trying to do that but I cant get it working.